# Connection failed: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: windows

I'm running the following PHP code (a pretty simple one):

```
<?php
$servername = "192.168.0.54";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

It's returning the following error:

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 7
>   Connection failed: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

SQL is running (on Windows Server) and I can log in with the same credentials.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ensure that port 1433 is open on the windows firewall on 192.168.0.54.

Comment: It is most likely firewall message; in addition to server firewall check client firewall settings too - xampp (apache?) may be blocked against making outgoing connections.

Comment: Sorry - my mistake. It turns out it's not mysql, but mssql :) I'm getting different errors now.